# LDAP Apache Directory Studio Authentication Failed

Tags: ldap, openldap, apache-directory

I am trying to integrate multiple directory services to Keycloak hence I am following the article: [Setup User Federation with Keycloak](https://documentation.abas.cloud/en/abas-keycloak/setup-user-federation-ldap.html)

I have pulled the docker data and running them as mentioned:

```
docker pull rroemhild/test-openldap
docker run --privileged -d -p 389:389 -p 636:636 --name da-01 rroemhild/test-openldap
```

Now I am trying to connect the same using the `Apache Directory Studio` and when I try to authenticate I get the message [image]

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I am trying with the mentioned password: `GoodNewsEveryone`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I basically tried running the docker in a different port and it worked:

`docker run --rm -p 10389:10389 -p 10636:10636 rroemhild/test-openldap`